# How to use gpiozero on RPi4 with Ubuntu 21.04, errored out NotImplemented

Tags: ubuntu, gpiozero

I'm trying to drive the motors from my RPi4.

On the RPi4 4GB RAM, I installed Ubuntu 21.04.

Here is the code, it used to be working on RPi Buster OS

```
# import os
# os.environ['GPIOZERO_PIN_FACTORY'] = os.environ.get('GPIOZERO_PIN_FACTORY', 'pigpio')

import time
# from gpiozero.pins.pigpio import PiFactory
from gpiozero import Motor, Device
#Device.pin_factory = PiFactory()
# from gpiozero.pins.native import  LocalPiFactory
# from gpiozero.pins.rpigpio import LocalPiFactory
# from gpiozero.pins.rpio import LocalPiFactory
# from gpiozero.pins.lgpio import LocalPiFactory

# ###
# drive motor: 0.5 - 1, turn motor : 0.2 -1
# ###
class Car:
    FORWARD = 'FORWARD'
    BACK = 'BACK'
    LEFT = 'LEFT'
    RIGHT = 'RIGHT'
    CURVE_LEFT = 'CURVE_LEFT'
    CURVE_RIGHT = 'CURVE_RIGHT'

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.motor_drive = Motor(6,13)
        self.motor_turn = Motor(12,16)
        self.turn_low_power = 0.2
        self.turn_high_power = 0.8
        self.step = (self.turn_high_power - self.turn_low_power) / 100.0
```

But once I changed the OS to Ubuntu 21.04, it stopped working.

Searched and found that I need to set up environment variables e.g. GPIOZERO_PIN_FACTORY and also need to install `gpiozero` and `pigpio` and I pip installed them and tried to use code to set the pin factory as you could see in the commented code etc.

But none of them works.
An error shows: NotImplemented on this line:
`self.motor_drive = Motor(6,13)`
[image]

Could someone show me how to make it work on Ubuntu 21.04?

**update 1**

I am told that Ubuntu 21.10 has support for gpio, so I tried to upgrade to it from 21.04 by following [a tutorial](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-to-21-10), I need to use the `-d` to get the 21.10 as it's not officially released for RPi platform.

But got the endless errors
[image]

**Update 2**

Finally updated to Ubuntu 21.10, but the code still not work:
[image]

So Ubuntu 21.10 does not support gpiozero by default.
Also tried to remove the environment variable in the code, still errorred out.

Anyone could help?

Comment: You need to use Ubuntu 21.10 which added proper GPIO support via the lgpio pin library. Read about it here: https://waldorf.waveform.org.uk/2021/the-pins-they-are-a-changin.html

Comment: hi @ben_nuttall thanks for your reply. I have read through the article you provided but not found Ubuntu 21.10 Impish mentioned in that article, but it does mention the Ubuntu Hirsute which is 21.04. Did I miss something?

Comment: @ben_nuttall I'm upgrading my RPi OS to Ubuntu 21.10 anyway. It's worthy to mention that 21.10 is not officially released for RPi, so I need to use the `-d` parameter to get it.

Comment: hi @ben_nuttall it's failed, please see my Update 1

Comment: hi @ben_nuttall I have tried, upgrading to 21.10 does not help.

Answer (score 0):

According to this page, (https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi) 20.04.3 and 21.10 servers and 21.10 desktop are supported for 64-bit operation.  I have the desktop running on a RPi4 8GB

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi mark, thanks for ur post, but I was asking the issue about GPIOZero issue, not about whether RPi supports Ubuntu or not.